# How to use Ashot in selenium to take screen shot for entire webpage

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit

I am not able to get results in selenium web driver using testng and maven
it displaying in console as

> java.lang.VerifyError: (class: junereleasemain/NewTest, method:
>   testFirstResult signature: ()V) Incompatible argument to function     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.(TestNGClassFinder.java:63)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:424)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:247)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:217)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:169)     at
>   org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_10.java:28)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_10.java:61)
>     at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:594)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:168)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:117)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1287)    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1141)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1075)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1047)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)

My ***script*** was

```
package junereleasemain;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.screentaker.ViewportPastingStrategy;

public class NewTest {

WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown() {
driver.quit();
}
@Test
public void testFirstResult() throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
driver.get("http://www.vpl.ca");
//take the screenshot of the entire home page and save it to a png file
Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(new    ViewportPastingStrategy(100)).takeScreenshot(driver);
ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "PNG", new File("c:\\temp\\home.png"));

WebElement searchField =   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='globalQuery']"));
searchField.click();
searchField.sendKeys("java");
WebElement searchButton =    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='search_button']"));
searchButton.click();

Thread.sleep(3000);

//take the screenshot of the entire results page and save it to a png file
screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(new ViewportPastingStrategy(100)).takeScreenshot(driver);
ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "PNG", new   File("c:\\temp\\results.png"));

WebElement searchResultLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@testid='bib_link'])[2]"));
searchResultLink.click();
Thread.sleep(3000);

//take the screenshot of the entire details page and save it to a png file
screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(new ViewportPastingStrategy(100)).takeScreenshot(driver);
ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "PNG", new   File("c:\\temp\\details.png"));

WebElement bookTitleElement =    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[@id='item_bib_title']"));
String bookTitleValue = bookTitleElement.getText();

assertEquals(bookTitleElement.isDisplayed(), true);
assertTrue(bookTitleValue.length()> 0);

}

}
```

Comment: You want to take screenshot of a webpage or screenshot of your logs?

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that the failure is probably because of two conflicting versions of the library used with some differences. Could you share the `pom.xml` as to what version of dependency you are using.

Comment: @KishanPatel,   want to take screenshot of a webpage

Comment: See the answer Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
 public class Screenshot {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://yahoo.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    File scrFile = (driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE));  
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("d:\\Selenium\\screenshot2.png"));
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any query. :-)

Comment: How to find duplicate text/records in webpage/table using selenium webdriver?  

 my qyuestoin is ,now iam directing to a web page, it contains n number of text, how can i find that webpage contains duplicate texts,,,,say in that page the text (Zebra )displayed/listed 2 times, it should find zebra as duplicate, like that i want the script for the above scenario

 
if webpage has thousands of texts, am i need to find only the duplicate records, i cannot search individually right? ..... i just want to print the duplicate records thats all

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What are those records/Text ?  tell me scenario

Comment: So when you say zebra as text. Where it is, i mean how it is shown ? It is just a text or some field ? Can you share a small screenshot? i need to know what type of text it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've been using aShot. It's nice because it captures the full page's image, and not just the current pane's view.

```
private void writeToFile(Path path) {
    try {
        path.toFile().mkdirs();

        Files.deleteIfExists(path);
        Files.createFile(path);

        LOGGER.debug("Writing screenshot to: {}", path);

        writeSsWithAShot(path);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Unable to capture and write screenshot to " + path.toString(),
            e
        );
    }
}

private void writeSsWithAShot(Path path) throws IOException {

    ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot aShot = new AShot()
        .shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1500))
        .takeScreenshot(driver);

    BufferedImage image = aShot.getImage();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", path.toFile());
}
```